# Delphi: How to call R functions (or integrate R) in/with Delphi?

Tags: mysql, r, function, delphi

Does anyone have a tip or example of how to use R functions in Delphi? I have used R and Delphi in an integrated way through MySQL I send input from Delphi to MySQL, run the function / on R script that connects to MySQL (package RMySQL) and it returns the output to MySQL, then use the Delphi . But this process is slow all depending on the size of the script R. Does anyone have an example or a tip to speed up the process?

This [website](http://mahendramahfood.blogspot.com.br/2007/12/how-to-access-r-engine-with-borland.html) had an example but all links are down. The code below shows a small example of how to use present R and Delphi.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, Datasnap.Provider,
  Data.DB, Datasnap.DBClient;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Edit2: TEdit;
    Edit3: TEdit;
    Label1: TLabel;
    Label2: TLabel;
    Label3: TLabel;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

uses Unit2;

function StartRAndWait (CommandLine : string) : Boolean;
var
    Proc_info: TProcessInformation;
    Startinfo: TStartupInfo;
    ExitCode: longword;
    CreateOK : Boolean;
begin
    Result := False;

    { Initialize the structures }

    FillChar(proc_info, sizeof (TProcessInformation), #0);
    FillChar(startinfo, sizeof (TStartupInfo), #0);
    Startinfo.cb := sizeof (TStartupInfo);
    Startinfo.dwFlags := STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW or STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
    Startinfo.wShowWindow := SW_HIDE;

    { Attempt to create the process. If successful wait for it to end}

    CreateOK := CreateProcess(Nil, PChar('C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.2\bin\x64\R.exe ' + CommandLine), nil,
       nil,False, CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP+NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, nil,
       nil, StartInfo, proc_info);
    if (CreateOK) then begin
       WaitForSingleObject (proc_info.hProcess, INFINITE);
       GetExitCodeProcess(proc_info.hProcess, ExitCode);
       Result := True
       end;
    CloseHandle(proc_info.hThread);
    CloseHandle(proc_info.hProcess);
    end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
    Command: STRING;
begin

  DataModule.ClientDataSet.Open;
  DataModule.ClientDataSet.Insert;
  DataModule.ClientDataSeta.AsFloat:= strtofloat(Edit1.Text);
  DataModule.ClientDataSetb.AsFloat:= strtofloat(Edit2.Text);
  DataModule.ClientDataSet.Post;
  DataModule.ClientDataSet.ApplyUpdates(0);
  DataModule.ClientDataSet.Close;
  Screen.Cursor := crHourGlass;
  try
    Command := 'CMD  BATCH  script.R  outputconsole.txt';
    StartRAndWait(Command);
  finally
    Screen.Cursor := crDefault
  end;

  DataModule.ClientDataSet.Open;
  DataModule.ClientDataSet.Last;
  Edit3.Text:= DataModule.ClientDataSetresult.AsString;
  DataModule.ClientDataSet.Close;

end;
end.
```

Comment: I don't think there's a way to make the R script go any faster (without making changes to the R script, of course), but you're blocking the main thread with this call and that isn't good.  It would be far better to run this in a thread - have it raise an event when the script completes and return the exit code if you need it.

Comment: Humm...it's true. I will try it.

Comment: @J... look my last comment in David ans, please. Is possible?

Comment: @Artur_Indio - Have you succeed calling a R function from Delphi? 
The link to Meme ( http://www.menne-biomed.de/download/RDcomDelphi.zip ) is broken. Do you have a copy?

Comment: @Altar I could not, even today I seek! And this too http://mahendramahfood.blogspot.com.br/2007/12/how-to-access-r-engine-with-borland.html

Comment: Please let us know if you made any progress with this :)

Comment: A possible cross-platform solution for Free Pascal is demonstrated in a discussion at https://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php/topic,40820.msg402598/. The approach for Delphi may be similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that this is not really a Delphi issue at all. You've provided Delphi code but it's really the R code that is important here. Your Delphi program simply starts a new R process, and waits for it to terminate. Yes there will be a little overhead involved with spinning up the new process, but my guess is that the bulk of the time is spent executing the R code.

So, if you want to speed up the entire calculation, the first thing to do is to speed up that part of the calculation which is taking the longest. Which appears to be the part executing under R.

It is possible to embed R in other processes. This could allow you to avoid waiting for new R processes to start up each time you want to execute your R code. However, embedding R is not the easiest thing to do. There are good R packages that make it easy to embed R in C++. I'm thinking of [Dirk Eddelbuettel's Rcpp suite](http://www.rcpp.org/), specifically Rinside. You could use that, or at least draw inspiration from it. However, I strongly suspect that embedding won't get around the root issue which is simply that your R code is taking longer to run than you would like.

Comment: Exactly, I also had the thought that everything actually depends on my spript R. Then call an R function in Delphi would be the best way, would not this interaction Delphi -> MySQL -> R -> Delphi. The site below he speaks of more RDCOM unable to access the files on it that had hosted him. I'll take a look at Rinside, should be easier to integrate because the R is written in C.

http://mahendramahfood.blogspot.com.br/2007/12/how-to-access-r-engine-with-borland.html

Comment: How will embedding speed things up?

Comment: Sorry I meant RCCP and not Rinside.

Comment: Perhaps the authors of this article below that used RDcom can provide me with the necessary files. Have a look on page 7.
http://www.uni-miskolc.hu/~fkt/Hundem_es_Geoinfo_2009/Cikkek/MagyariSaskaZs_DombaiI.pdf

Comment: Yes, but how will embedding speed things up? You seem to be clutching at straws here. If the time is spent executing the R code, embedding won't help you with speed.

Comment: Ahh I understand now. So you think that even if I call a function of direct R in Delphi, for example quantile (), I'll spend the same time I'm spending in the way I described above?

Comment: Absolutely. Exactly the same code will be running on the machine. Embedding just gives you convenience for interop. The execution performance will be the same. In fact, if you embed and then make multiple calls into R, you might find it slower than a single call to R that runs a complete R script. Fundamentally, if you want to improve performance you must first understand where the time is being spent and then think about possible optimisations.

Comment: So thank you very much. Actually I would have the job without having the expected result. So I will concentrate on the R code and then continue to use the way I'm doing. I plan on using a temporary file to process the data (csv, txt, xls) instead of connecting R and Delphi to MySQL I would give Delphi entry in a. Txt ai would run the process in R that would give a output in. txt, and then load on delphi. Another way would be to read and write in the. RDATA format, but this I do not know.

Comment: I noticed one thing that is making the process slower, when I create the process R loads some packages and script runs and then ends. If I trigger the process again it will load the packages again. Is there a way to trigger the process when leaving it running in the background until you close the form? Then when you open the form I load the R and leave it in the background on how you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do that through "ShellExecute" and there is no need to  TProcessinformation and TStartupInfo.